# Saxon custom xpath function arguments

Tags: java, xml, xpath, saxon

I am writing a custom xpath function that is supposed to receive one element as argument. I am using saxon to register and execute function.
For example if i have xml structure

```
<b>
<a>1</a>
<a>2</a>
</b>
```

and expression `a:foo(/b/a[1])` where foo is custom function, for first argument i receive list of one element. If element is passed as variable i will not get a list. Is there some way to make saxon to return for this `/b/a[1]` single element instead of list of one element?

Comment: There is no representation of "a single node" in XPath. You can have a node-set that consists of one element - which is exactly what you see. Implement your function in a way that it uses only the first node of any node-set you pass in.

Comment: You've omitted some important information. (a) what language is your "custom function" written in: XSLT, XQuery, Java, C#? (b) how is it declared?

Answer (score 0):

> If element is passed as variable i will not get a list.

Presumably this is a variable with a declared type that requires a single element:

```
<xsl:variable name="theNode" select="/b/a[1]" as="element()" />
```

I suspect (I'm sure Michael Kay will correct me if I'm wrong) that when you use the expression `/b/a[1]` directly, its static type is inferred to be a sequence type (such as `node()*` or `element()*`) rather than a single node since it's possible at runtime that the expression could match nothing (such as if there are no `a` elements) or more than one node (if there's more than one `b` at the top level of the current tree<sup>1</sup>), you could try using the "treat as" construct to override this:

```
a:foo(/b/a[1] treat as element())
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Yes, this is possible, if the current context node is part of a temporary tree which is a fragment rather than a well-formed document, e.g. `<xsl:variable name="fragment"><b><a/></b><b><a/><a/></b></xsl:variable>`